# Cannot access the per-site metas of only a few SE sites

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, per-site-meta

I’m experiencing a very strange error these days; not sure if it started yesterday or two days ago. When trying to access the meta-sites of [German](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com), [Travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com), [Anime & Manga](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com) and [Academia](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com). I get the following error message displayed as black text of my browser’s standard font on a white background:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault**. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

For some weird reason, I can access [TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com)’s and [Chemistry](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com)’s meta-sites without any problems.

This problem, as I saw earlier, only occurs when I am logged in. Just opening a browser and checking if German Meta was down, I was able to access it, and I was able to click the login button and log in. But once I was logged in, I got the error. The login process worked: When I entered German’s address into the address line I reached German and was logged in.

Further testing just reveals that it applies to *all* SE sites where I have an account except for TeX and Chemistry. Random tests in communities that I did not join allowed access to the respective metas.

**Update:** As of two days later, I can now again access Travel’s meta. German and A&M are still hidden. Maybe this issue will be resolved as meta server caches reset?

Comment: I just checked my meta-profiles on those sites and I can't repro. I don't think it is related to your local setup but can you try with a different browser and state the browser you're using. There have not been account-merges for you recently, right?

Comment: @rene There has been an account merge on TeX.SE. My browser is Firefox.

Comment: And an account merge on Chem? I'm watching you, Jan ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @DEAD /Ina: Chem =/= TeX ô.o

Comment: Well, if that's the reason you can access meta.TeX . . .

Comment: Oh *that*’s why you brought that up xD

Comment: Did you try with different browser? Or after clearing all cookies and cache?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Cookies are deleted upon exiting Firefox. Cache clearing didn’t work. Neither does different browser. (IIRC, it first turned up on my work PC so a totally different one from the one I’m at now.)

Comment: So I'm afraid something is borked with your meta account.. just to make sure, if you browse in Private mode you can access the meta sites, right? (i.e. without logging in.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I always log out on leaving SE, and when I opened the browser today I just entered meta.German to 'see if it works', which it did — until I logged in on meta.

Comment: So it confirms that it's a problem with your meta account(s) - will need to wait for a dev to fix that, or if it's some sort of weird server side cache, wait for the cache to expire/reset itself.

Comment: Looks like the link with your networkprofile got borked on the merge: [this is the one from Meta.German,SE](http://stackexchange.com/users/1648268/jan?tab=accounts) and this one form [meta.tex.se](http://stackexchange.com/users/1633881/jan?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Jan lol no worry, you couldn't really know. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as of today I can visit all metas I care about again. (This time, I didn’t go through every single account of mine to compare whether I can access that site’s meta — I don’t visit most sites regularly enough.)

Apparantly something got borked upon the account merging that happened in TeX.SX. And from how the meta sites ‘slowly came back’ one by one (in the order Travel – German – Anime), [I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

If somebody *actually* has insight into the hidden points and can answer this question properly, please feel free to.